# How to run Jupyter notebook from html webpage just by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I want to run a jupyter notebook in backend corresponding to an onclick of a button designed using HTML,CSS and JS.
What are options available and how can I do this?

Comment: you can use py-script

https://dev.to/devsmitra/what-is-pyscript-and-why-should-you-care-10f

Comment: @RahulSharma — I'd be very surprised if jupyter notebook could be run using py-script.

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. Jupyter Notebook is a client-server system. Once set up the server bit is generally running all the time, and the client bit provides its own buttons. I think you need to provide more detail about what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Quentin is spot on. We really cannot tell what you are trying to do? There's so many ways to run a notebook these days that you'd have to be more thorough for anyone to really help you.  I was thinking you are looking for JupyterLite that runs the Python-related computational aspects inside the browser on the local machine using Web Assembly & can be hosted as static sites because of that. (Plus, the title of your post is vague to the point of being unrelated to the 1st line of your post. I think that is why Rahul thought of pyscript. If you are fixing up this post, please fix title, too.)

Answer (score -1):

This can not be achieved using HTML, CSS or JS because they are rendered on the client side. This means that the code doesn't run on the server it is hosted on. However PHP is server side rendered. This means that the code runs on the server first.

An example using PHP to run a python script:

```
exec("python3 path/to/python_script");
```

An example to run the PHP script that runs the python script in html:

```
<form action="path/to/php_script">
    <button>Execute python file</button>
</form>
```

Or you can use the  tag:

```
<a href="path/to/php_script">Execute python file</a>
```

When clicked on one of the buttons above you will be redirected to the php script and it will execute the python file.